# Why does StartCopyAsync() throw 409 Conflict when GenerateIfNotExistsCondition used for destination?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I want to copy a blob to another storage account if the destination one does not exist. But I must be misreading the documentation on [StartCopyAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.startcopyasync?view=azurestorage-8.1.3#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_CloudBlockBlob_StartCopyAsync_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_File_CloudFile_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_AccessCondition_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_AccessCondition_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_BlobRequestOptions_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_OperationContext_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) and [GenerateIfNot​Exists​Condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.accesscondition.generateifnotexistscondition?view=azurestorage-8.1.3#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_AccessCondition_GenerateIfNotExistsCondition) because I thought I could do it in one call (without having to check destination existence in a separate one) with something like this:

```
    await _targetClient.StartCopyAsync(
        _schemaBlob, 
        null, 
        _schemaBlob.Name, 
        AccessCondition.GenerateIfNotExistsCondition(), 
        null, 
        ContainerName, 
        cancellationToken);
```

But it throws a `409 Conflict` if the destination blob exists. Isn't that the point of the `AccessCondition.GenerateIfNotExistsCondition()` parameter to ensure that the operation will just do nothing when the blob exists?

How to do it right?

Answer (score 3):

> But it throws a 409 Conflict if the destination blob exists. Isn't that the point of the AccessCondition.GenerateIfNotExistsCondition() parameter to ensure that the operation will just do nothing when the blob exists?

On Azure Storage Service side, it will do nothing and just return a 409 status code. On your client side, if the return code is not equal 200, a exception will throw. I suggest you add a try-catch blob to your code and do nothing in the catch blob.

```
try
{
    //put your copy code here
}
catch (StorageException ex)
{
    //If the exception is 409, just skip the exception
    if (!ex.Message.Contains("409"))
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you could check whether the target blob is exist before do the copy command.

```
if (targetBlob.Exists())
{
    //do the copy here
}
```

> The behavior of leaving this parameter null and initialized to what I did is the same.

It might contains some errors in your code. There are 2 AccessCondition, one is for source blob, another is for target blob. Here is a sample method. If you change the value of target AccessCondition to null. The target blob will override by source blob.

```
public static async void CopyBlob(Uri sourceBlob, CloudBlockBlob targetBlob, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
   string text  = await targetBlob.StartCopyAsync(
       sourceBlob,
       //Source blob access condition, it will check whether the source is exist. If source doesn't exist, a exeception will throw.
       Access​Condition.GenerateIfExistsCondition(),
       //Target blob access condition, it will check whether the target is exist. If target blob exist, 409 error will occur.
       AccessCondition.GenerateIfNotExistsCondition(),
       null,
       null,
       cancellationToken);
}
```

Here are my test code. Please note that if your source container is private, you need to provide source blob URI with SAS to the first parameter of StartCopyAsync method.

```
Uri sourceUri = new Uri("Put your source blob uri with SAS");

string targetConnectionString = "target blob connectionString ";
CloudStorageAccount targetStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(targetConnectionString);
// Create the blob client.
CloudBlobClient targetBlobClient = targetStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

CloudBlobContainer targetContainer = targetBlobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer2");
CloudBlockBlob targetBlob = targetContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("text1.txt");

CopyBblob(sourceUri, targetBlob, new System.Threading.CancellationToken());
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, but I'm not sure what's the point of the access condition then? The behavior of leaving this parameter `null` and initialized to what I did is the same.

Comment: Any updates? Have you tried my suggestions? If you have further questions, please feel free to let me know.